# iOS device is not listed in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have done the provisional profile and it is showing properly in Organizer.  Iphone device is also listed and next to it is a green little circle.

However, in xcode the device is not listed and can not be picked.

What can be the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Have you click on "use for development" in organizer?

Answer (score 6):

Click on your top project item, and check the Summary tab on your target.

Under Devices if you have selected iPad then it won't let you build to your iPhone.

Also, if the deployment target is higher than the version on your device it might not work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the following?

- Restart Xcode
- Restart the iOS Device
- Restart your computer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and following worked for me in XCode 6.1

1: Open Devices (Window>Devices)
[image]

2: Select Device

3: Go to settings and Mark 'Show in Run Destination Menu'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues that could be causing this.

**1. Incorrect provisioning** - Verify that you have specified the correct provisioning profile in "debug" in the build settings for both the project AND the target.  Then make sure that that same provisioning profile has that device authorized on it (Apple Provisioning Portal) and that the profile has been installed on the device.

**2. Proper deployment target value**

**3. Device Type** - Make sure that your project is set for the correct device type (iPhone or iPad or Universal).

**4. Restart Everything**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue.  My problem was that I had accidentally installed the same provisioning profile twice.  So when I clicked "Provisioning Profiles" (from the drop-down tree in Organizer below my device) it listed 2 instances of it -- one where the Team field showed my name and one where the Team field listed "Unknown".  I deleted the "Unknown" instance and my device immediately showed up in my available devices list for testing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a simple case of having the deployment target set too high.  I started the project on Xcode 7.3.1 on my work machine... but when I got home, I opened up the project with Xcode 7.2 (which does not have the 9.3 SDK).  After changing it to the proper deployment target, voila... good to go.

And by simple, I mean I restarted, cleaned and screwed around with it for about 20 minutes before I smacked my head and saw the problem.  :-)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For `VMware` Users

Goto menu VM->Settings->USB Controller->Change USB Compatibility 3.0 to 2.0 and then Check show all usb devices.

This worked for me. Now xcode is showing connected iphone device.

If `show all usb devices` option is disabled, power off virtual machine and try.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was the following:

Go to Project and click on your Target.
Then, navigate to the General tab. Under Minimum Deployments I was targeting iOS 16.6, but my devices were only up to 16.4.
I switched it to iOS 16.4 and they immediately showed up as available devices.

Comment: Answers from 12 years ago mention that you need to check the deployment target. No need to add another answer stating the same thing.